# How to remove a software installed by dpkg -i FILE.deb?

Tags: debian, dpkg

For example, Opera web browser is distributed as a deb file, and can be installed by the command `dpkg -i opera.deb`. How to remove it?

Comment: did you try `dpkg -r package_name` yet ?

Comment: Does `man dpkg` offer any suggestions?

Comment: `apt-get remove pkgname` or `apt-get purge pkgname` will work, regardless whether it is installed correctly or incorrectly, so long as it is uninstallable.

Comment: @FaheemMitha How do I know the pkgname?

Comment: Well, it's probably `opera`. But try `dpkg -l | grep opera` and see what you get.

Answer (score 12):

First, find out what the package name is (which may or may not be the same or even similar to the `.deb` filename...but usually is at least similar):

```
dpkg -I opera.deb | grep 'Package:'
```

then remove that package, using either `dpkg` or `apt-get` (or `apt` or `aptitude` etc etc etc).

```
dpkg -r packagename
```

Optionally use `--purge` rather than `-r` if you want to completely remove the package, including conffiles.

You can even remove it in one line with something like this:

```
apt-get purge $(dpkg -I opera.deb | awk -F: '/Package/ {print $2}')
```